# Passing a json object to asynctask class from activity class

Tags: android, object, android-asynctask

I'm trying to send a `json` object and few String data to `asynctask` to communicate with the `api`. I'm using the following code and in that I can pass only `String` values (all the values I'm passing from activity are `Strings`).

I know how to create an object and I have already created it. I want to know how to pass a `JSON` object and other strings at once.

Can anyone help me with this.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

These are the data I want to pass to asynctask,

[image]

**activity,**

```
new GetAllDiscountsAsyncTask(getBaseContext(),
        new OnTaskCompleted() {

        @Override
        public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

            System.out.println("GetAllDiscountsAsyncTask");
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            CardPromotionListActivity.class);

        }
}).execute(CartItemEntitys, OrderID, OutletCode,
        equiredDate, Total);
```

**Asynctask class**

```
public class GetAllDiscountsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray> {
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    private JSONArray responseJson = null;
    private Context contxt;
    private Activity activity;
    String email;

    public GetAllDiscountsAsyncTask(Context context, OnTaskCompleted listener) {

        // API = apiURL;
        this.contxt = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // async task to accept string array from context array
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

        String path = null;
        String response = null;
        HashMap<String, String> request = null;
        JSONObject requestJson = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = null;
        StringEntity requestString = null;
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = null;

        Log.i("CardNo", "0");
        Log.i("CartItemEntity", params[0]);
        Log.i("DiscountCode", "0");
        Log.i("OrderID", params[1]);
        Log.i("OutletCode", params[2]);
        Log.i("PayCode", "0");
        Log.i("PhoneNo", "0");
        Log.i("RequiredDate", params[3]);
        Log.i("Total", params[4]);

        try {
            path = "http://203.94.69.162:3331/ItemService.svc/GetAllDiscounts";

            new URL(path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            // set the API request
            request = new HashMap<String, String>();
            request.put(new String("CardNo"), "0");
            request.put(new String("CartItemEntity"), params[0]);
            request.put(new String("DiscountCode"), "0");
            request.put(new String("OrderID"), params[1]);
            request.put(new String("OutletCode"), params[2]);
            request.put(new String("PayCode"), "0");
            request.put(new String("PhoneNo"), "4545");
            request.put(new String("RequiredDate"), params[3]);
            request.put(new String("Total"), params[4]);

            request.entrySet().iterator();

            // Store locations in JSON
            requestJson = new JSONObject(request);
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(path);
            requestString = new StringEntity(requestJson.toString());

            // sets the post request as the resulting string
            httpPost.setEntity(requestString);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Handles the response
            responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

            responseJson = new JSONArray(response);
            System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + responseJson.length());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        try {
            responseJson = new JSONArray(response);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return responseJson;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        listener.onTaskCompleted(responseJson);
    }

}
```

**Json Object**, in activity class

At the moment I convert this to String and send it to the asynctask, but I want to send without converting,

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

    jsonObj.put("MainMenuCode",item.getMainMenuCode());
    jsonObj.put("Price", item.getPrice());
    jsonObj.put("Quantity", product.getQuantity());
    jsonObj.put("SubMenuCode",item.getSubMenuCode());

    String a = jsonObj.toString();
    CartIddtemEntityList.add(a);
    CartItemEntitys = CartIddtemEntityList.toString();
```

Comment: where is the JSON object that you need to pass?

Comment: so you need to pass jsonObj to the webservice that  your using! is that what you are asking for?

Comment: yes, But I have one json object and 8 Strings to send as shown in the screen shot in my question.

Comment: got it! check out my answer hope it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so first create a new `JSONObject` and lets call it `jData`:

```
JSONObject jData = new JSONObject();
```

then add your current `jsonObject` to it:

```
jData.put("Result",jsonObj);
```

finally:

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("YourUrl");
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jData.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This way I got the json object but I have small problem what happened to other 8 Strings? how can I pass them.

Comment: you can simply add them to the jsonObject